# Calculating averages from a CSV export

Tags: excel, vba

I have the output of a 360 Review software. CSV export of the dummy data below.

- The first column is the type of Reviewer (Manager, Direct Report or Self Review).
- The second column is the name (in reality e-mail address) of the individual being reviewed.
- Columns C and onwards are the output of their questions rated 1-5
- There are two rows of headings. The first row is the "theme of the question" the second row is the question number. A theme can have multiple questions in it.
- The software splits the questions into two columns where self review has its own column. I tried to combine them but failed.

I'd like to calculate:

A - Average score of each employee across all their questions and all review types
B - Average score of each employee but separated by themes (not questions)
C - Average score of each employee but separated by each review type across all questions

```
relationship_to_reviewee,reviewee_email,Theme1,Theme1,Theme1,Theme1,Theme2,Theme2,Theme3,Theme3,Theme4,Theme4,Theme5,Theme5,Theme6,Theme6
,,Q1,Q1,Q2,Q2,Q3,Q3,Q4,Q4,Q5,Q5,Q6,Q6,Q7,Q7
Direct report,Alice,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,,5,,1,
Direct report,Alice,5,,5,,3,,1,,2,,4,,4,
Manager,Alice,5,,4,,4,,5,,3,,3,,4,
Manager,Alice,5,,4,,5,,5,,3,,3,,3,
Self review,Alice,,5,,2,,1,,3,,4,,5,,4
Direct report,Bob,1,,3,,3,,1,,3,,3,,1,
Direct report,Bob,2,,3,,3,,2,,3,,3,,2,
Manager,Bob,3,,1,,4,,5,,4,,4,,5,
Manager,Bob,4,,1,,4,,5,,4,,4,,5,
Self review,Bob,,5,,4,,1,,3,,4,,5,,4
```

I tried:

- Manually by highlighting all the cells I want and I could calculate the averages. The output is below (the averages are slightly off as data changed a little). But this is quite manual.
- An Averageif statement. I can get it to work across one column and therefore one question but it doesn't seem to work across all the questions. =AVERAGEIF(B3:B12,"Alice",C3:P12)
- I tried writing a macro with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old school but as first help as excelformula:

{=AVERAGE(IF(B3:B12="Alice",IF(C3:P12="","",C3:P12),""))}

the curly brackets are done with ctrl+shift+return - matrix
so put in
=AVERAGE(IF(B3:B12="Alice",IF(C3:P12="","",C3:P12),""))

and press ctrl + shift + return

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what you want for an output format, but this can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`

  - ***Be certain to NOT select `My Table has headers`***
  - System will generate a list of headers:  `Column1, Column2, ...`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],

//Get list of Themes and Q's
    #"Themes" = List.RemoveFirstN(Record.FieldValues(Source{0}),2),
    #"Q's" =  List.RemoveFirstN(Record.FieldValues(Source{1}),2),

//Set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {
        {"Column1", type text},
        {"Column2", type text}
        & List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2), each {_, type any})}),

//Unpivot EXCEPT first two columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column1", "Column2"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Split off the Number from the Attribute column to get the column number => location in the list of Themes or Q's
//Then remove the unneeded "Attribute.1" column and set the Data type for the Column number
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(
            #"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", 
            Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition((c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c), {"0".."9"}), 
            {"Attribute.1", "Column"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Split Column by Character Transition",{"Attribute.1"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Column", Int64.Type}}),

//Remove the top rows of the unpivoted table
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Changed Type1", (Table.ColumnCount(Source) - 2) * 2),

//Add columns to denote applicable Theme and Question
// then remove the "Column" column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Top Rows", "Theme", each Themes{[Column]-3}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Q's", each #"Q's"{[Column]-3}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Column"}),

//Group by reviewee
// then aggregate by Pivoting for Theme and Q
//    and also an overall Average
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Column2"}, {
        {"Average by Theme", (t)=>
            Table.Pivot(
                Table.SelectColumns(t,{"Value","Theme"}),
                List.Distinct(t[Theme]), "Theme","Value", List.Average)},
        {"Average by Q", (t)=>
                Table.Pivot(
                    Table.SelectColumns(t,{"Value","Q's"}),
                    List.Distinct(t[#"Q's"]), "Q's","Value", List.Average)},
        {"Overall Average", each List.Average([Value]), type number}}),

//Re-expand the Grouped tables
//Then set the data types
    #"Expanded Average by Theme" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Average by Theme", List.Distinct(#"Themes")),
    #"Expanded Average by Q" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Average by Theme", "Average by Q", List.Distinct(#"Q's")),
    #"Set Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Average by Q", List.Transform(
                List.Distinct(#"Themes") & List.Distinct(#"Q's"), each {_, type number})),

    #"Rename Column2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Set Types",{{"Column2", Source[Column2]{0}}})
in
    #"Rename Column2"
```

Given your posted data example, this is the result:

[image]